# How to check current cursor shape in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, cursor, qwidget

Qt 4.8 on Fedora 17 x64

In my `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent`, I am trying to check to see if the cursor is currently set to either `Qt::SizeVerCursor` or `Qt::SizeHorCursor`, but the `QCursor` returned by calling `QWidget::cursor()` cannot be compared to either `Qt::SizeVerCursor` or `Qt::SizeHorCursor` because of a compile error.  It looks like this is because both `Qt::SizeVerCursor` and `Qt::SizeHorCursor` are actually `Qt::CursorShape` instead of `QCursor`.

This code fails to compile:

```
void MyGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
    if( ( cursor() == Qt::SizeHorCursor ) || ( cursor() == Qt::SizeVerCursor ) )
    {
        qDebugGreen() << "Cursor is a size cursor!";
    }

    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent( event );
}
```

Here is the compile error:

`error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘QWidget::cursor() const() == (Qt::CursorShape)6u’`

How can I check if the current cursor is either `Qt::SizeVerCursor` or `Qt::SizeHorCursor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imho cursor().shape() should work.

Comment: Yep, that compiles, thanks.  Does each widget have it's own cursor?  It keeps coming back as `0` even though I can see that the cursor is one of the shapes I'm checking for.  The widget whose `cursor()` I'm calling is not the one that set it to a size shape.  Is this expected?

Comment: In documentation is that if no cursor is set, or after a call to unsetCursor(), the parent's cursor is used.
And by default this will return Qt::ArrowCursor, which has value 0.
try calling setCursor() before.

Comment: After experimenting around, it looks like the cursor to check is the `cursor()` for the top level item.